# Logs for postStart are not printing

Tags: kubernetes, containers, podspec

I am using below example to test postStart and preStop hooks.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: aaaa
  labels:
    wwww: qqqq
spec:
  containers:
  - name: adassa
    image: nginx:1.10.1
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ['bash', '-c', 'echo 11111111']
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ['bash', '-c', 'echo 2222222']
```

My pod was successfully created, but later when I tried to check the hooks output using `kubectl logs aaaa -c adassa` and `kubectl logs aaaa` then there were no logs.

I tried but not able to pinpoint the issue. I thought maybe shell issue, so I changed `bash` to `sh` but after this even Pod was not created.

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PostStart event:**

The echo output is inside the container scope so it does not show/log anything.
For executing a command i use:

> command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 11111111> /tmp/message"]

There are several logging approaches however writing on a file as above is a simple example and for testing purposes.

Once you create a pod, execute interactive to get a shell and finally check if lifecycle trigger wrote on the sample file this way.

> kubectl exec -it aaaa -- /bin/bash
>
> cat /tmp/message

You should get:

> 11111111

Refer to [this](https://logz.io/blog/a-practical-guide-to-kubernetes-logging/) guide for different logging approaches, think about a 3rd party

Comment: ok thanks, let me try this out today.